# How can i write my code snippet in a cleaner way so that it is easy to read and least possible lines?

Tags: java

I am having a small piece of code in my project. There are too many if condition. How can I rewrite it better to make it more readable, remove any redundancy etc and cleaner way? I am using Java 8.

```
private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User createSpringSecurityUser(String lowercaseLogin, User user) {

    if (user.getAccount() != null) {
        PrimecastAccount account = primecastAccountRepository.findOneBySystem(user.getAccount())
            .orElseThrow(PrimecastAccountNotFoundException::new);

        if(account.getAccountType().equals(AccountType.INTERNAL)) {

            if ( !account.getStatus().equals(AccountStatus.ACTIVE)) {
                throw new DisabledException("User " + lowercaseLogin + " account not ACTIVE");
            }

            if (!user.getActivated()) {
                throw new UserNotActivatedException("User " + lowercaseLogin + " was not activated");
            }
        } else {
            if ( !account.getStatus().equals(AccountStatus.DISABLED)) {
                throw new DisabledException("User " + lowercaseLogin + " account not ACTIVE");
            }
        }

    } else {
        if (!user.getActivated()) {
            throw new UserNotActivatedException("User " + lowercaseLogin + " was not activated");
        }
    }

    List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = user.getAuthorities().stream()
        .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getLogin(),
        user.getPassword(),
        grantedAuthorities);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to CodeReview! Please add a description of what your code does and also change the title accordingly.

Comment: done i have changed . let me know it makes sense

Comment: Unfortunately, not really. The title should tell the people who read it, what your code does. What problem does it solve?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! The current question title, which states your concerns about the code, is too general to be useful here. Please [edit] to the site standard, which is for the title to simply state the task accomplished by the code. Please see [How to get the best value out of Code Review: Asking Questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436) for guidance on writing good question titles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Code Review and thanks for sharing your code.

The usual approach is that you identify parts of your code that do (exactly) the same and transform the code so that the duplicated lines can be merged.

In your case you have three lines duplicated:

```
if (!user.getActivated()) {
            throw new UserNotActivatedException("User " + lowercaseLogin + " was not activated");
        }
```

The main problem is, that one of the occurrences is inside an `if` block. But if you take a closer look at this nested occurrence you can see, that it does not depend on the condition checked with the `if`. Therefore it is safe to move this three lines up before the `if` and delete the other occurrence. This also makes the `else` block completely obsolete.

---

What I don't like in this code is that your method mixes concepts. The upper part is *procedural programming* while the lower part is *functional programming*.
Within a method you should stick to one concept only.
The usual approach to this is to put the different parts in separate methods called from the original method:

```
private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User createSpringSecurityUser(String lowercaseLogin, User user) {
   checkUserData(lowercaseLogin,user);
   List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities =
      convertAuthoritiesOf(user);
 return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getLogin(),
        user.getPassword(),
        grantedAuthorities);
}

checkUserData(String lowercaseLogin, User user) {
    if (user.getAccount() != null) {
    // ...
    }
}

convertAuthoritiesOf(User user){
    return user.getAuthorities().stream()
        .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

another way would be to convert one part to the same concept as the other:

```
private org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User createSpringSecurityUser(String lowercaseLogin, User user) {

    Stream.of(user)
          .filter(User::getActivated)
          .findFirst()
          .orElseThrow(()->new UserNotActivatedException("User " + lowercaseLogin + " was not activated"));

    PrimecastAccount account = Stream.of(user)
          .map(u->primecastAccountRepository.findOneBySystem(user.getAccount()))
          .findFirst()
          .orElseThrow(PrimecastAccountNotFoundException::new);

    Stream.of(account)
          .filter(AccountType.INTERNAL.equals(PrimecastAccount::getAccountType))
          .filter(PrimecastAccount::getActivated)
          .orElseThrow(()->new UserNotActivatedException("User " + lowercaseLogin + " was not activated"));

    Stream.of(account)
          .filter(Predicate.not(AccountType.DISABLED.equals(PrimecastAccount::getAccountType)))
          .orElseThrow(()->new UserNotActivatedException("User " + lowercaseLogin + " was not activated"));

    List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = user.getAuthorities().stream()
          .map(SimpleGrantedAuthority::new)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
    return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getLogin(),
        user.getPassword(),
        grantedAuthorities);
}
```

**Attenion**: your code has logical errors which I did not fix.

Answer (score 1):

The validation part that throws could be placed in its own method - maybe.

`AccountType` and `AccountStatus` seems enums, or might be due to implement as enums. Then `==` / `!=` can be used.

*Donnot-Repeat-Yourself* and introducing variables makes for a more compact notation.

```
PrimecastAccount account = null;
if (user.getAccount() != null) {
    account = primecastAccountRepository.findOneBySystem(user.getAccount())
        .orElseThrow(PrimecastAccountNotFoundException::new);
}
if (!user.getActivated()) {
     throw new UserNotActivatedException("User " + lowercaseLogin + " was not activated");
}
if (account != null) {
    AccountType type = account.getAccountType();
    AccountStatus status = account.getStatus();
    if (type == AccountType.INTERNAL && status != AccountStatus.ACTIVE)
            || (type != AccountType.INTERNAL && status != AccountStatus.DISABLED) {
        throw new DisabledException("User " + lowercaseLogin + " account not ACTIVE");
    }
}
```

This focuses on giving only different exceptions. For the same behavior unfortunately you would still do something to only call `findOneBySystem` once.